# How to expand an action view in ActionBar that contains an Edit Text?

Tags: android

I have the following task -

> When you press the Add button, the action bar should expand an action
>   view that contains an Edit Text and a Button called "Save".

I did the following for testing purposes:

[image]

I know how to add all these widgets to `Action Bar`. I'm just getting confused with this phrase - "action bar should expand an action view that contains an Edit Text" and a Button. How do I implement this? Thank you.